# How can you find the number of cells changed from an SQL UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql, count, sql-update

Say you have the following table:

[image: Car Table]

*If the image doesn't load, the table contains car names, their brand and whether they're in a sale*

Now, let's say the car dealership decides to put all Skodas and Minis on sale, this SQL command can be used:

> UPDATE cars SET `InSale`=True WHERE `Brand` in ("Skoda", "Mini")

*Words in `code` are me trying to put ` around them*

Which works. However, it would be useful to return how many cells changed value, so in this case 3, because the Rapid and Countryman were already in the sale, so they don't count

Is there any command I can run in/after the SQL above to return cells changed? The only idea I have is using some form of COUNT command, but I'm not sure how to implement such a thing

Comment: You can run `select count(*) from cars where InSale` before and after your update. it will tell you the count of rows where InSale = true. The difference in counts will tell you how many rows were updated.

Comment: I was initially thinking of doing something like this, but the command has to be run twice, which isn't very efficient, especially if the database is large

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SQL%ROWCOUNT` to get the count of records updated by your `UPDATE` statement.
You may have to modify your `UPDATE` statement so that correct number is captured by `SQL%ROWCOUNT`.

```
UPDATE cars SET InSale=True WHERE Brand in ("Skoda", "Mini") and not InSale
```

Comment: Quite good. `InSale <> True` can be shortened to `not InSale`. +1

Comment: Thank you! - just what I was looking for. How would the statement look for the `SQL%ROWCOUNT`?

Comment: @Oliver That depends on the specific database and driver. Each one has a slightly different implementation. What's your database, and what's the app language you are using?

Comment: I'm using PHP to run commands on a phpMyAdmin database